# Abstract Algebra- Proving normality

Tags: abstract-algebra

A problem from Intro to Abstract Alegebra by Hungerford.

*Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$ and let $N = \bigcap\limits_{a\in G} a^{-1}Ha $.  Prove that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$*

I'm having difficulty understanding what $N = \bigcap\limits_{a\in G} a^{-1}Ha $ is.
$a^{-1}Ha = \{a^{-1}ha\ |\ h\in H \wedge a\in G\}$

Can anyone help understand this problem and how to approach?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, now take the intersection of all such sets.

Comment: Is it right to say that an element is a member of $N = \bigcap\limits_{a\in G} a^{-1}Ha$ only if $\forall a_{i},a_{j} \in G,\ a_{i}^{-1}Ha_{i} = a_{j}^{-1}Ha_{j}$?

Comment: No, you are taking the intersection of all such sets.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little bit confused.  If $N$ is the intersection of all those sets, and if $g \in G$ were a member of $N$.  I thought it would mean $\forall a \in G\ \exists h\in H:\ g = a^{-1}ha$.  

Or in otherwords that $\forall a_{i},a{j} \in G\ \exists h_{1},h_{2}:  g = a_{j}^{-1}h_{1}a_{j} = a_{i}^{-1}h_{2}a_{j}$.

Comment: A nicer(?) way to prove the result itself: $G$ acts by conjugation on the set of subgroups that are conjugate to $H$. This give us a homomorphism from $G$ to the corresponding symmetric group. $N$ is the kernel of this.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks, I think that uses some things from ahead chapters, but I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element $g\in G$ belongs to
$$
N=\bigcap_{a\in G}a^{-1}Ha
$$
if and only if, for all $a\in G$, there is $h\in H$ such that $g=a^{-1}ha$.

Now, take $g\in N$ and $b\in G$: you want to prove that $b^{-1}gb\in N$. If $a\in G$, write $g=(ab^{-1})^{-1}h(ab^{-1})$

> This is possible by hypothesis. Then $b^{-1}gb=b^{-1}ba^{-1}hab^{-1}b=a^{-1}ha$.
> Since $a$ is arbitrary, we have $b^{-1}gb\in N$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I proved it as well in a slightly different way.  If you have time please take a look.  But thank you for your response.
An element $g \in N$ only if $\forall a_{i},a_{j} \in G\ \exists h_{1},h_{2}: g = a_{j}^{-1}h_{1}a_{j} = a_{i}^{-1}h_{2}a_{i}$.  More simply it says that $\forall a \in G,\ g = a^{-1}ha$ for some $h \in H$.

Then if $$g = a_{j}^{-1}h_{1}a_{j} = a_{i}^{-1}h_{2}a_{i}\\
\rightarrow (a_{i}a_{j}^{-1})h(a_{j}a_{i}^{-1}) = h_{2}\\
\rightarrow (a_{j}a_{i}^{-1})^{-1}h(a_{j}a_{i}^{-1}) = h_{2}$$

Then since $a_{j}a_{i}$ is arbitrary, $h_{2}$ is in $N$ and $N$ is normal

Comment: @DavidJhoo It's almost the same as my reasoning.

Comment: can you say where you might think it is wrong?  If $g$ is in $N$ then is it true that $\forall a \in G: g = a^{-1}ha$ for some $h$ in $H$, as you posted.  Is it the same to say that $g= a_{j}^{-1}h_{1}a_{j} = a_{i}^{-1}h_{2}a_{i}$ for arbitrary $a_{j},a_{i}$ and some $h_{1},h_{2}$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DavidJhoo I didn't say it's wrong.

Comment: Ok sorry, I'm still looking at my answer to see if it's correct.  I'm not really sure :)